# Как выполнить остановку потока?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, потоки-данных, qthread

Есть функция в mainwindow.cpp.

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_2_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    ui->textEdit->clear();

    ui->label_2->setText("TableView clicked");

    int IndexOfID = model2->record(index.row()).value("ID").toInt();
    QString A = ui->lineEdit->text();

    qDebug() << index;

    pMyThread = new QThread;
    pNumGen = new NumGenerate(index, IndexOfID, A);
    pNumGen->moveToThread(pMyThread);

    connect(pNumGen, SIGNAL(emitNumbers(QString)), this, SLOT(update(QString)));
    connect(pMyThread, SIGNAL(started()), pNumGen, SLOT(generate()));

    if(pMyThread->isRunning()){       
        pMyThread->quit();
        pMyThread->wait();
        delete pMyThread;
    }

    pMyThread->start();
}
```

Хочу остановить выполнение потока. Для для этого написал

```
if(pMyThread->isRunning()) {       
    pMyThread->quit();
    pMyThread->wait();
    delete pMyThread;
}
```

Действия внутри потока:

```
void NumGenerate::generate()
{
    qDebug() << "IndexOfID: ";
    qDebug() << IndexOfID;
    QSqlQuery query;

    QString myQueryOfIndex;

    A.replace(" ", " & ");

    myQueryOfIndex = QString("SELECT \"TextOfFile\" as ttt FROM \"Table\" Where \"ID\"=%1 ").arg(IndexOfID);

    QString Alltext;

    query.exec(myQueryOfIndex);

    int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf("ttt");

    if (query.next()) {
        Alltext = query.value(fieldNo).toString();// Забираю весь текст из одной записи
    }

    //Рассматриваем таблицу NewTable и колонку Text
    QString myQueryOfText = QString ("select \"Text\" from \"NewTable\" where to_tsvector(\'russian_hunspell\', \"Text\") @@ to_tsquery(\'russian_hunspell\', \'%1\') ").arg(A);

    query.exec(myQueryOfText);
    QString NEW;

    int IndexOfMytext = 0;
    int IndexOfFragOfNEW = 0;
    int con = 0;

    while (query.next()) { // Пока есть записи в результате myQueryOfText запроса
        //Вначале Mytext = книга
        QString Mytext = query.value(0).toString();// Одно значение записи (1-книга, 2-книги, 3-книге...)

        qDebug() << "Вывод Mytext:";
        qDebug() << Mytext; // Уточнение: какое именно значение мы проверяем ниже

        //Старый способ, находит только индекс первого вхождения
        //IndexOfMytext = Alltext.indexOf(Mytext, Qt::CaseInsensitive) != -1

        //NewAlltext = Alltext; //Обновляю NewAlltext, потому что потом буду изменяться и обрезаться

        int pos = 0; //Позиция вхождения

        qDebug() << "Начальная позиция: ";
        qDebug() << pos;


        //Пока есть вхождения, то надо копировать фрагмент и в нем окрашивать слова
        while((IndexOfMytext = Alltext.indexOf(Mytext, pos, Qt::CaseInsensitive)) != -1) {
            qDebug() << "Позиция при вхождении: ";
            qDebug() << pos;

//--Новое
            // Кол-во соответствий внутри всего текста

            con++;
            qDebug() << "Это соответствие номер: ";
            qDebug() << con;

            //2
            int StartPos = IndexOfMytext - 25; //С какой позиции символа копировать
            int LengthFrag = (Mytext.length())+40; //Копирование строчки такой длины

            //Вырезаю фрагмент из Alltext из всего текста
            QString FragOfNEW = Alltext.mid(StartPos, LengthFrag);
            qDebug() << FragOfNEW; //Показываю какой фрагмент у меня есть

            //3
            //Индекс вхождение книга в маленький фрагмент
            IndexOfFragOfNEW = FragOfNEW.indexOf(Mytext, 0, Qt::CaseInsensitive);

            //Удалить слово с позиции IndexOfFragOfNEW,
            //длиной Mytext - слово из NewTable
            FragOfNEW.remove(IndexOfFragOfNEW, Mytext.length());

            QString HtmlCod = "<span style=\" font-size:8pt; font-weight:600;\">"+Mytext+"</span>"; // HTML код форматирования

            NEW = FragOfNEW.insert(IndexOfFragOfNEW, HtmlCod); //Вставить слово на позицию IndexPro, и что именно вставить

            qDebug() << NEW; //Вывести весь измененный фрагмент

            //4
            QStringList ListFragOfNEW = NEW.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts);

            qDebug() << ListFragOfNEW;

            ListFragOfNEW[0] = "...";
            ListFragOfNEW[(ListFragOfNEW.length())-1] = "...";

            qDebug() << ListFragOfNEW;

            QString Result = ListFragOfNEW.join(" ");

            qDebug() << Result;

            emit emitNumbers(Result);

            Sleep(250);

            // передвигаем начальную позицию для indexOf
            pos = IndexOfMytext + HtmlCod.length();

            qDebug() << "Позиция когда передвинули ее: ";
            qDebug() << pos;
        }//Конец второго цикла. Была проверка по старому слову
        //Начинаю проверку по новому слов
    }//Конец цикла первого while
}
```

Хочу реализовать такую идею:

> если мы первый раз нажимаем на первую ячейку tableView, то выполняется
> поток, если же мы опять нажимаем только уже на вторую ячейку, я хочу
> чтобы этот поток останавливался и потом начинался заново, выполняя
> действия с исходными данными из второй ячейки.

При этом ожидается такое развитие событий:

> нажимаю на первую ячейку, выполняется этот поток с данными из первой
> ячейки, в процессе выполнения этого потока, я нажимаю на вторую ячейку
> и ожидаю прекращения работы потока с данными первой ячейки и начало
> его работы с данными уже из второй ячейки.

Пока у меня каждое нажатие это новый поток, и при каждом нажатии появляются новые потоки, и они выполняются одновременно.

Подскажите как можно реализовать мою идею? Как сделать остановку потока? Что в таком случае лучше сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо немного исправить код обработки клика:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_2_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    //...

    // Останавливаем и удаляем предыдущий поток бежит он, или нет
    if(pMyThread != nullptr){       
        pMyThread->quit();
        pMyThread->wait();
        delete pMyThread;
        pMyThread = nullptr;

        // Рабочего тоже надо удалить (в этом месте это безопасно, потому что его поток уже удален)
        delete pNumGen;
    }
 
    // Создается новый со свежими входными данными
    pMyThread = new QThread;
    pNumGen = new NumGenerate(index, IndexOfID, A);
    pNumGen->moveToThread(pMyThread);

    connect(pNumGen, SIGNAL(emitNumbers(QString)), this, SLOT(update(QString)));
    connect(pMyThread, SIGNAL(started()), pNumGen, SLOT(generate()));

    pMyThread->start();
}
```

Comment: Безопасно ли сравнивать поток с nullptr? Ведь оператор delete после выполнения никак не перезаписывает указатель, который ему передали.

Comment: @maestro да, не безопасно. Исправил. Спасибо за замечание